# Sharepoint Site List Graph API Query

Tags: curl, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

We have a SharePoint list in this URL

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SubDivision/Lists/Fake%20Data/AllItems.aspx
```

Now we've been trying to list down the contents via graph API curl

The call to this URL works fine.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/SubDivision
```

However, we can't seem to get it to display the list.

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer [token here]" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SubDivision/lists
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com:/sites/SubDivision
```

it returns info about the site like this.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites/$entity",    
    "id": "mycompany.sharepoint.com,010e3a98-...-43c0bfca1433,7d96e68c-...-b6538b8c1284",
    "name": "SubDivision",
    "webUrl": "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/SubDivision",
    "displayName": "SubDivision"
}
```

To be able to get the collection of list you need to take `id` and use it in this call

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer [token here]" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompany.sharepoint.com,010e3a98-...-43c0bfca1433,7d96e68c-...-b6538b8c1284/lists
```